# Hide Vertical Scroll bar in Facebook Page Tab (New)

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to remove vertical scroll bar in facebook page tab  when its width is set to 810px.

Please note that I talking about iframe in **Facebook Page Tab** when its width is set to normal(810px). There is no height option in backend.

I have searched a lot but every one is talking about old facebook page tab that had a width of  520px.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function:

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810, height: 1050 });
```

As part of this full setup, which goes right after the opening  tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({appId:YOUR_APP_ID_HERE,status:true,cookie:true,xfbml:false});
        FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810, height: 1050 });
    };
    (function(d, debug){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document, /*debug*/ false));
</script>
```

Next, make sure you don't have any css that is setting the overflow-y property on the html element to "scroll".  I've seen css resets that set this property.